# Laravel standard role on user registering

Tags: laravel

Please note: I am pretty new to laravel and programming in general.

So in my laravel application I want newly registered users to get a standard role 'user'. I followed a tutorial but it doesn't seem to be working, because I am not getting new entries in my 'role_user' table.

**RegisterController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
  use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'user')->first());

        return $user;
    }
}
```

**users migration**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

**roles migration**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('roles');
    }
}
```

**role_user migration**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateRoleUserTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('role_user');
    }
}
```

**User model**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'roles_id'
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
    public function authorizeRoles($roles)
    {
        if (is_array($roles)) {
            return $this->hasAnyRole($roles) || 
                    abort(401, 'This action is unauthorized.');
        }
        return $this->hasRole($roles) || 
                abort(401, 'This action is unauthorized.');
    }
    /**
    * Check multiple roles
    * @param array $roles
    */
    public function hasAnyRole($roles)
    {
        return null !== $this->roles()->whereIn(‘name’, $roles)->first();
    }
    /**
    * Check one role
    * @param string $role
    */
    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        return null !== $this->roles()->where(‘name’, $role)->first();
    }
}
```

**Role model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

So my question is, why aren't new registered users getting the 'user' role assigned within the role_user table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A silly mistake that you might forget. You should not return the following.

```
return $user = User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
]);
```

The code in `RegisterController` should be like this.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'user')->first());

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: That's it, thanks, it's working now!
(Along with adding use App\Role; to my RegisterController)

Answer (score 0):

You have early return in create method in controller